# What's a good way to ensure delivery of an entire message when using raw tcp?

Tags: json, node.js, tcp, go, buffer

Say I have an application that on the backend I want to use raw tcp so that I can have bi-directional communication between different services. In this application I want to send over a payload consisting of a json object, when the json data is sent, every few messages, it gets cut off and the remainder is then clumped to the next response.  I don't want to use something like say websockets due to the time used to upgrade from http.  What is a good (and hopefully best) way to ensure that that json object will go from one node and be read from another node as the **whole** json object?

I know sending and receiving buffers of a set size and a message for a heartbeet are the rule of thumb, but can I see an example? Preferably in Javascript (node's net stdlib) or Golang (it's net stdlib) because those are my most proficient languages, though I don't really care what language it is done in ultimately.

(I know there's a few questions out there asking similar things regarding ensuring delivery of message with tcp, but none asked for an example that I found)

I know tcp is a stream. I'm just asking of a way to ensure that when writing a specific json object to this stream, how do I ensure I get the same json object on the other end, as in "send json object X from node a, ok node b received *that same object* X"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a heartbeat, or fixed size messages for delivery confirmation. If you need to ensure delivery, you need an application level acknowledgement. If you need to ensure delivery of the *correct* message, you'll need to include a unique message ID to acknowledge. If you need to ensure that the message is unaltered, you'll need to include a checksum or MAC.

Here it sounds like you're having trouble with message framing. While there are many ways to frame your messages (simple length-prefix, [type-length-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type-length-value), HTTP/1.1, etc.), a simple solution is to use the built-in `json.Encoder` and `json.Decoder`.

Example client, which sends a "PING" message every second:

```
type Message struct {
    Payload string
}

func sendMessages(c net.Conn) {
    message := Message{}

    encoder := json.NewEncoder(c)

    for i := 0; ; i++ {
        message.Payload = fmt.Sprintf("PING %d", i)
        err := encoder.Encode(message)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
}
```

Example Server:

```
type Message struct {
    Payload string
}

func receiveMessages(c net.Conn) {
    m := Message{}

    decoder := json.NewDecoder(c)
    for {
        err := decoder.Decode(&m)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("Received: %#v\n", m)
    }
}
```

Comment: Well yeah, that is obvious.  I'm asking to ensure the entire message arrives.  Sometimes the json will get cut off.

Comment: @ChristianGrabowski: TCP guarantees in-order delivery, and since you're sending json, the syntax provides a way to check if an object is complete. Do you want a way to ensure delivery without parsing the json? Do you want to include a signature to ensure the message is unaltered?

Comment: I'm saying that when the json data is sent, every few messages, it gets cut off and the remainder is then clumped to the next response.  Clearly it's cutting off at X paclets for some reason and then continuing.

Comment: @ChristianGrabowski: TCP doesn't have "messages", it's a stream. The stream is broken up into packets, and depending on the timing of your reads, you may read any portion of those in a single operation, up to the size of your read buffer. It's not "cutting off" anything, you just need to read more from the stream. That said, you can use a length-prefixed message protocol to aid in reading the stream, or something like `json.Encoder/Decoder` which will delimit multiple json objects with newlines. Maybe post an example of what you've tried, and where things are going wrong.

Comment: Yes I know it is a stream. I'm just asking of a way to ensure that when writing a specific json object to this stream, how do I ensure I get the same on the other end. I'm not understanding what's unclear.

Comment: @ChristianGrabowski: Maybe you're just not wording things precisely, but your last comment indicates you're missing something. Your message is never "cut off" over TCP, unless you encounter a new message before the old one completed, or the connection is broken. Otherwise, it's a problem with how you're handling the stream.

Comment: Yes there is another message being sent.  My question is how to ensure the next message doesn't break the first message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88808/discussion-between-jimb-and-christian-grabowski).